# How to fix java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.Map?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, shadow-dom

I'm trying to access an element inside `shadowDOM`

```
WebElement selectorElement = testConfig.driver.findElement(By.tagName("measure-builder-editor"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) testConfig.driver;
Object shadowRoot = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", selectorElement);
String id = (String)((Map < String, Object > ) shadowRoot).get("shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf");
RemoteWebElemententer code here remoteWebElement = new RemoteWebElement();
remoteWebElement.setParent((RemoteWebDriver) testConfig.driver);
remoteWebElement.setId(id);
WebElement SecondDiv = remoteWebElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.editor-panel"));
WebElement mainDiv = SecondDiv.findElement(By.className("cl-content"));
mainDiv.click();
mainDiv.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT);
mainDiv.sendKeys(type);
```

It is running fine when running in local but when I'm trying to run this on Jenkins it is throwing the error.

I'm running this through TestNg and Selenium.

```
java --version

openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: that's some pretty crazy casting going on there...  does Jenkins use the same version of Selenium?  (3 or 4?)  Also is java run-time the same version?

Comment: yes jenkins have the same versions of everything as local